# generate bank account token using android from stripe

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe on my android project. I know that you can generate stripetoken for card using this.

```
Card card = new Card("4242424242424242", "12", "2014", "123");

Stripe stripe = new Stripe("pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
stripe.createToken(
    card,
    new TokenCallback() {
        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
            // Send token to your server
        }
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            // Show localized error message
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
              error.getLocalizedString(getContext()),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
    }
)
```

I am using their [stripe-android](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android) library from github

So How can I generate stripeToken for BankAccount?

I can't seem to find any example on google about this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to have customers pay directly from a bank account, so there's no API to create a payment token using bank details. Maybe you're thinking of the '[Marketplaces](https://stripe.com/us/marketplaces)' product which let's you setup recipients with bank details and make transfers *to* them (eg, to pay out earnings).

Comment: but i am using stripe on php side so how to handle or create token for webservice in my android app???

Answer (score 2):

You can create using this code.

```
  Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2";

  Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  Map<String, Object> bank_accountParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  bank_accountParams.put("country", "US");
  bank_accountParams.put("currency", "usd");
  bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_name", "Jane Austen");
  bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_type", "individual");
  bank_accountParams.put("routing_number", "11000000");
  bank_accountParams.put("account_number", "000123456789");
  tokenParams.put("bank_account", bank_accountParams);

  try {
    Token s = Token.create(tokenParams);
     Log.d("Token",s.getId());
  } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
     //showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
  } catch (CardException e) {
     //showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
  } catch (APIException e) {
     //showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
  } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
     //showAlertMessage("", e.getMessage());
  } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
     //showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: Hello Madhan, You need to create your own stripe key to test this code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the new docs you need to add following line to gradle build:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
```

check for the latest version at this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android)

Then use the following code snippet:

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this);
stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("your_publishable_key");
BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount("accountNumber","countryCode","currency","routingNumber");
stripe.createBankAccountToken(bankAccount, new TokenCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        Log.e("Stripe Error",error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(com.stripe.android.model.Token token) {
        Log.e("Bank Token", token.getId());
    }
});
```

This should work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

hi simply try below code with ur stripe api key

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this, "YOUR API KEY");

        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount("000123456789","US","usd","110000000");
        stripe.createBankAccountToken(bankAccount, new TokenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception error) {
                Log.e("Stripe Error",error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(com.stripe.android.model.Token token) {
                Log.e("Bank Token", token.getId());
            }
        });
```